# Misma llave para actualización de aplicación Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, deployment

Actualmente tengo un problema cuando trato de desplegar la ACTUALIZACIÓN de una app a la Google Play Console, según el error presentado:

> Error en la carga Tu Android App Bundle está firmado con una clave no
> válida. Asegúrate de que contenga la clave de firma correcta y vuelve
> a intentarlo: SHA1: etc

Siguiendo las indicaciones para el despliegue de una aplicación elaborada con Flutter, tengo que ejecutar un comando semejante a:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Los datos que debe contener el archivo son los mismos, la clave es igual, mismo nombre de archivo, etc.

La pregunta es: utilizando el comando indicado, el archivo que se genera es el MISMO que el utilizado cuando subí la aplicación por primera vez a la Google Play Console ??  Supongo que de ser así no me debería aparecer el problema actual que tengo, pero no me deja de aparecer el error que les indico.  Agradezco su colaboración

Comment: El archivo key que usaste la primera vez debe ser el mismo siempre, sino no podrás subir updates

Comment: @diegoveloper agradezco tu comentario, pero no responde la pregunta: si sigo LOS MISMOS pasos, si utilizo LOS MISMOS DATOS, etc., el archivo que se genera es EL MISMO que el generado inicialmente ??  (diferente en hora de generación, pero SUPONGO que igual en cuanto al contenido; agradezco tu ayuda)

Comment: no, es diferente, el archivo debe ser el mismo , si una vez lo subiste con el archivo X, entonces el update debe ser con el mismo archivo, no debes generar uno nuevo, solo usa los datos del primer archivo, CON el primer archivo obviamente. https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reference-the-keystore-from-the-app

Comment: OK @diegoveloper, gracias!